# imperavi redactor for yii icons not loading

Tags: php, css, yii, redactor

I am trying to integrate the redactor wysiwyg to my Yii application. The wysiwyg is loading and functioning. But, the Icons don't show (snapshot here - http://i58.tinypic.com/ily4nq.jpg). I copied https://github.com/yiiext/imperavi-redactor-widget to the extension directory and called the widget in my _form view. Code below -

```
echo $form->labelEx($model, 'content');

    Yii::import('ext.imperavi-redactor-widget.ImperaviRedactorWidget');
    $this->widget('ImperaviRedactorWidget', array(
        // You can either use it for model attribute
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'content',
        // Some options, see http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/
        'options' => array(
            //'lang' => 'ru',
            //'toolbar' => true,
            //'iframe' => true,
            //'css' => 'wym.css',
            'minHeight' => '250',
            'buttons' => array(
                'formatting', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'deleted', '|',
                'unorderedlist', 'orderedlist', 'outdent', 'indent', '|',
                'video', 'image',
                'link', '|', 'html',
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

What could be the problem? The CSS and JS are loading properly. There is an EOT font file and I made it available in multiple places just in case without luck. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There was a CSS class conflict. I was loading another CSS (system.css) that had a font-family element that was conflicting with the external font being used for redactor wysiwyg. I commented it out and icons show!

Answer (score 0):

Use console (F12) to check if requested files are ok.
"Network" tab will help you.

If you got 404, that means you probably need to check and fix the path to images in CSS.

Comment: Yes. I did. I don't get a 404 on any file and the paths seem to be ok. does it have to do something with jquery loading after the rendering? I am so confused and have spent hours trying various possibilities and searching online for similar issues and solutions..